# What privilege is required to preserve ownership of a file on copy, and how do you get it?

Tags: linux

I have a homework question about kernel programming in Linux. The question is:

> What Linux-specific privilege is required to preserve ownership of a file when it's copied, and how do you get it?

Through experimentation, I've found that I need to be `root` or a superuser to get this to work. Is there a more specific way to explain this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [`capabilities(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) manual page – you need the `CAP_CHOWN` capability to change file ownership via `chown()`. (Root has all capabilities enabled automatically. The manual page explains how to obtain capabilities in other cases.)

There is no separate method/capability to just *preserve* ownership, as Linux file copies are made by simply reading/writing data to the destination file, then doing the same with metadata. (For comparison, Windows NT has `SeBackupPrivilege` and `SeRestorePrivilege` privileges and the `BackupRead()`/`BackupWrite()` calls.)

Comment: Sweet, thank you. I had no idea where to look.